# How to achieve this blur effect with css

Tags: css

I'm trying to get this cloud-like/gaussian blue effect, but I can't quite get it.  I've tried using drop shadows with the same background color but it's not exactly right.  Anyone know how to do it?
[image]

Comment: i don't see a blur, but a box-shadow  and background ;)

Comment: You probably have to continue playing with css to achieve a specific custom effect like that. Or maybe use DevTools and see how they did it? Possibly with a overlaid SVG or something else...

Comment: You can also use radial gradient as a overlay.

Answer (score 0):

The given image doesn’t look so much like a CSS drop shadow as mentioned in the question, more like an image put in an element on top of which is a div with something like a linear gradient, or even multiples of these, semi transparent.

This sort of thing

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(255,255,255,0.5));
```

But more sophisticated. Playing around with tones and opacities and positioning is probably the only way to get exactly what is wanted, the good thing about linear gradients being they let you do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the SVG image. You can add SVG image in CSS file or you can add SVG code in HTML file. I am not able to attach SVG file here.

This is the final output.

[image: This is a final demo image]

```
    <style>
    body{
        /*background-image: url("#"); Add background Image*/
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        display: flex;
        height: 100vh;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 800px;
        max-height: 800px;
    }
    .container{
        width: 800px;
        height: 800px;
        /*background-image: url(".svg");*/ 
        /*or .svg code in html file*/
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
</style>
    
<body>
    <div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can view Demo here : [link](https://jsfiddle.net/NupurJ/hy8Luzqd/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a pseudo-element of the `.splash` container, makes it smaller than it's parent. On that pseudo-element, I have a partially transparent background and a box-shadow.

I do need to place all children of said container on top of the pseudo-class.

As you can see, the background begin to fade before the edge of the parent element that contains all text.

```css
section {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #121212
}

.splash {
  --splash-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  --splash-background-size-decrement: 60px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.splash > * {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;  
}

.splash::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--splash-background-size-decrement);
  right: var(--splash-background-size-decrement);
  top: var(--splash-background-size-decrement);
  bottom: var(--splash-background-size-decrement);
  
  background-color: var(--splash-background-color);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 60px var(--splash-background-color);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="splash">
  
    <h1>Some text here</h1>
    
    <p>Some text here. Some text here</p>
    
    <p>Some text here. Some text here</p>  
  
  </div>
<section>
```